# How to configure JavaMail for Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft Exchange (2010) mail account using JavaMail 1.5.1. When I try to connect, I get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
    Couldn't connect to host, port: domain server, 25; timeout -1;
      nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
public class SendMail 
{
    public void mail () throws MessagingException
    {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String protocol = "smtp";

        // Setup mail server
        props.put("mail." + protocol + ".host", "domain server");
        props.put("mail." + protocol + ".auth", "true");
        props.put("mail." + protocol + ".port", "25");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        Transport t = session.getTransport(protocol);

        try{
            t.connect("domain\\user name", "password");

        }
        finally{
            t.close();
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

*Replace* **domain server** *with the actual server name in exception and code.*

Comment: have you tried with smtps and have you verified the port ?

Comment: Try these [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  Is your code running in an app server where the security manager might be preventing you from connecting?

Comment: I believe the problem is one or all of the following:
1. Wrong port
2. Incorrect credential format (not "dom\juser\J.User" as they suggest in the FAQ).
3. Protocol is wrong. 
I'll have to talk to the who set up the Exchange server for more details (he is on vacation).

Answer (score -2):

[SMTP is not started by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3218422/351861) on exchange servers so i'd recommend simply [using exchange itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28309972/351861)

Comment: SMTP is a Transport protocol, IMAP is a Store protocol.  They're not interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, hopefully that's obvious.  Nonetheless, you recommended switching from SMTP to IMAP, which isn't going to solve the problem.  Switching to one of the Microsoft proprietary protocols **might** solve the problem, if the problem is that the Exchange server is not configured to allow SMTP access.

Comment: Maybe you could consider updating your original answer to better explain what you think is obvious?  Or not.  Your choice.

Comment: Since it is not as obvious to me, can someone explain?

Comment: Explain what, exactly?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I send mails with IMAP?

Comment: @specializt - you do realize that IMAP is _retrieve_ while SMTP is _send_, right?